# Transform Facebook Graph API insights JSON to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read my Page INSIGHTS from Facebook graph API and then convert into pandas dataframe but unable to do so.

I used json_normalize function but i did not help me

Here is my JSON

```
    [{'name': 'page_impressions',
      'period': 'day',
      'values': [{'value': 0, 'end_time': '2020-01-02T08:00:00+0000'},
       {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2020-01-03T08:00:00+0000'},
       {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2020-01-04T08:00:00+0000'},
       {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2020-01-05T08:00:00+0000'},
       ],
      'title': 'Daily Total Impressions',
      'description': "Daily: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, check-ins, ads, social information from people who interact with your Page and more. (Total Count)",
      'id': '761993803915367/insights/page_impressions/day'},
     {'name': 'page_fans',
      'period': 'day',
      'values': [{'value': 587, 'end_time': '2020-01-02T08:00:00+0000'},
       {'value': 587, 'end_time': '2020-01-03T08:00:00+0000'},
       {'value': 587, 'end_time': '2020-01-04T08:00:00+0000'},
       {'value': 587, 'end_time': '2020-01-05T08:00:00+0000'}],

      'title': 'Lifetime Total Likes',
      'description': 'Lifetime: The total number of people who have liked your Page. (Unique Users)',
      'id': '761993803915367/insights/page_fans/day'}]
```

**Sample Expected Output in dataframe**

```
page_impressions  | page_fans  |  end_time

 0                587       2020-01-03T08:00:00+0000
```